# Is there any text editor for Mac that can be configured to have, or already has, autocomplete for Lua?

Tags: autocomplete, lua, syntax-highlighting, text-editor

I know TextWrangler shows the option, but it doesn't actually do anything. So what I want is autocomplete, either with a key combination, or while I type.

Syntax coloring/highlighting is a requirement as well, though I know Xcode and TextWrangler have that.

Comment: Well, aparently XCode actually has auto-completion. Waddaya know....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [Lua Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt) for this purpose. It has syntax coloring, plus it is doing smart autocomplete, depending on what your actual context is (required modules, ...)

It is an Eclipse Technology project, and it is Open Source! (EPL license).

- Project web page - http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt
- Installation via Eclipse Marketplace - http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/lua-development-tools-koneki

Comment: This site is *really* weird...this is where I ended up, following the "Download" link in the page you provided: https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/koneki-ldt/40/ and I can't figure out how to download the bloody thing!

Comment: Hi OddCore. I am sorry if you had difficulties figuring out how to install the tool, I agree that the instruction were maybe a bit confusing.  
I have reworked the project web page, so hopefully it should be easier to understand now. Also, I encourage you to use the Eclipse Marketplace which simplifies the installation process a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice [plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Home) for Lua. IntelliJ IDEA is really nice, though kind of biggish.

Aside of that there is also [TextAdept](http://foicica.com/textadept/) which is a lot smaller, and 100% configurable in Lua.

And probably a bunch of others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have seen this page, but it seems a good place to start:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaEditorSupport

If I search for "completion" I get:

- [Decoda](http://www.unknownworlds.com/decoda) (Win)
- [LuaEdit](http://luaedit.luaforge.net/) (Win)
- [DForD](http://www.dfordsoft.com/cs/lua_index.htm) (Win)
- [NsEditor](http://apocalyx.blogspot.com/2008/06/nseditor-v31-is-released.html) (Win)
- Visual Studio + [LuaLite](http://www.sjbrown.co.uk/index.php?code=lualite)
- Eclipse + [LuaEclipse](http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/) or [LunarEclipse](http://lunareclipse.sourceforge.net/) (java)

I personally use Vim + SuperTab (which only auto-fills with things that you have previously written).

Answer (score 0):

If you want full (semantic) autocompletion, you should try [lua-inspect](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaInspect) ([source code](https://github.com/davidm/lua-inspect)), which can be installed in the [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) editor, and also into ViM using [vim-lua-inspect](https://github.com/xolox/vim-lua-inspect).

It uses [Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/) to fully parse the source code into AST and then performs code analysis. Apart from simple keyword-based syntax highlighters, it can:

- differentiate between local/global variables, parameters and unused variables
- jump to the definition of a variable/function
- autocomplete table members
- correctly rename variables/functions (not only definitions but also uses)

Even though it is not yet stable, and tends to hang on large scripts, it is very usable for standard Lua programs, mainly for it's intelligent autocompletion and renaming.